# How to password-protect my Local Disk D in Windows 10 Home (Local Disk C contains my OS)?

Tags: windows-10

1. I use Windows 10 Home; ['Encrypt contents to secure data'](https://www.windows10forums.com/threads/how-to-password-protect-a-file-or-folder.10564/) is unavailable for me:

[image]

2. I still cannot operate [VeraCrypt](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6169/use-truecrypt-to-secure-your-data/) that raises [too many problems for me](https://superuser.com/q/1193229/269574).
3. Windows 10 Home lacks [BitLocker Drive Encryption](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766295(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_S3). See also [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/01/12/securing-windows-10-with-bitlocker-drive-encryption/).

Comment: In Veracrypt there should be an option for "Encrypt a non-system partition/drive" when you click on Volumes > Create new volume. Just click back on the screen you are on now and it should be the middle option. From there you should be able to select drive D

Comment: Your question HEADER says you want to encrypt a FOLDER in another drive, but the body of your message makes me understand you want to encrypt the whole drive D: , which one is it? with veracrypt both things are done differently. I just downloaded veracrypt and this is the window I get, options 1 and 2 seem to be what you need. http://i.imgur.com/GHAFvdG.png

Comment: @arana Sorry. Corrected now.

Comment: @music2myear Yes to your first question: see 1.

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal - You should not use the title of your question to share specific details.  Your question body should be modified to include that information.  Considering multiple people have missed the edition of Windows you are using because its only located in the title, you should considering modifying the question body, to include that information.  Your question still does not explain the reason, you cannot use Veracrypt in any significant detail, Veracrypt is more then capable of encrypted a non-system volume.